# Android Webiew does not load indexed Sdcard (file://sdcard)

Tags: java, android, mobile, browser, webview

When I tried to access (file:///sdcard/) using mobile browsers (ex. Firefox, Opera ..etc). It shows me an index page for the SDCard (see the screenshot).

[image]

However, when I access the same url using a webview and give it a storage permission and does not show the Index page. My code is below:

```
package com.example.webbrowser;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

class NetworkState {

    public static boolean connectionAvailable(Context context){

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() !=null;
    }
}

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        return true;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    EditText editText;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Button back, forward, stop, refresh, homeButton;
    Button goButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.web_address_edit_text);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
        forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward_arrow);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        goButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go_button);
        refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        homeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        } else {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                    progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                    if (newProgress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (newProgress == 100) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    }else{
                        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void go_button(View view) {
        try {
            if(!NetworkState.connectionAvailable(MainActivity.this)){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {

                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                webView.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());
                editText.setText("");
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void home_button(View view) {
        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
    }

    public void refresh_button(View view) {
        webView.reload();
    }

    public void stop_button(View view) {
        webView.stopLoading();
    }

    public void forward_button(View view) {
        if (webView.canGoForward()) {
            webView.goForward();
        }
    }

    public void back_button(View view) {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Android mainifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.webbrowser">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WebBrowser">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help ?

Comment: `I tried to access (file:///sdcard/)` Well i dont see that url in your code...

Comment: On which device and Android version Chrome and Chrome version  behaves like that? It does not here.

Comment: check the latest version. android 10 should be fine, you need to grant chrome storage permission @blackapps

Comment: That does not work on my Android 10 device. And file:///sdcard is still not in your code.

Comment: @blackapps the code is just a web view which receive a url from edittext (see this line)    ```webView.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());```  when you pass the url file:///sdcard after running it will not work. Beside, you can test the url in chrome android 10 or 11 in android emulator. It work for me in Samsung device. Make sure to give a storage permission when prompted.

Comment: `webView.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString())` Ridiculous. If you are asked to show what you do you have yo write webView.loadUrl("file:///sdcard');` Only then we see that you use it in your code. You should only post minimal reproducable code here.